# How to use RTLD_DEEPBIND when invoke implicitly?

Tags: c, linux, shared-objects, dlopen, shared-libraries

Now i have 3 shared objects,A.so,B.so,C.so

```
    A.c    
    void libA()  
    {  
        common();  
    }  

    B.c
    void common()  
    {  
        printf("COME HERE B\n");  
    }  

    C.c
    void common()  
    {     
        printf("COME HERE C\n");  
    }  
    (just ingore the .h files)

    test.c
    int main()  
    {  
      libA();    
      return 1;  
    }  

complie:  
gcc -fPIC -shared libB.so libB.c  
gcc -fPIC -shared libA.so libA.c ./libB.so  
gcc -o test test.c libC.so libA.so
```

I wish result to be "COME HERE B" and i could use `dlopen` with `RTLD_DEEPBIND` flag,
but it costs too much time to change functions from implicit call to explicit call in my project.
Is there anyway to solve this problem?

`gcc -Wl,-Bsymbolic` doesn't work in this solution.

Well, if A.c contains implementation of common. It does work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when the dynamic linker searches for a symbol in runtime, it chooses the first one that it comes across. The search order depends on the order of libraries in `DT_NEEDED` section of the binary, which in turn depends on the exact order of libraries in the command line during compilation.
So, make sure `libB.so` is before `libC.so` on the command line when compiling `test.c`.